# How to describe return type of function which is result of call passed generic function

Tags: typescript, generics, types

The question is how to describe the **return type** of function **bar** which should be the result of execution of generic function **fn**.

`function foo(fn<T>) /*return →*/ function bar<B> /*return →*/ call fn<B>()`

Example:

```
function foo<T extends <X>(...args: any) => any>(fn: T) {
    return function bar<B>(): ReturnType<typeof fn> /***/ {
        return fn<B>({ /*config*/ });
    }
}

{
    const f1 = <T>() => Promise.resolve(({/*input*/ } as T));
    const x1 = foo(f1)
    const y1 = x1<{ a: 'A' }>()/**Promsise<unknown>❌*/.then(data => data.a); // should be Promise<{ a: 'A'}> ✅
    const y12 = x1<{ b: 'B' }>()/**Promsise<unknown>❌*/.then(data => data.b); // should be Promise<{ b: 'B'}> ✅
}

{
    const f2 = <T>() => ({/*input*/ } as T);
    const x2 = foo(f2)
    const y2 = x2<{ a: 'A' }>()/**unknown❌*/.value // should be { a: 'A'} ✅
    const y21 = x2<{ b: 'B' }>()/**unknown❌*/.value // should be { b: 'B'} ✅
}
```

Thanks

**Update 1** :

TypeScript related issues

- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37181
- https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40542

Comment: what are X and B generics types used for in your foo definition ? Your are not using them ?

Comment: Both are used. **X** - is needed to describe generic function **fn** as parameter. **B** - is used in the calls `x1` or `x2` and set to `{value: 'value'}`

Comment: maybe but X is not used in your function declaration. so still do not understand

Comment: `X` is used in `extends`. The code means that type `T` should be **a generic function** `T extends <X>(...args: any) => any`. Try to remove `X` and see that TypeScript don't allow you to call `fn` as generic function `fn<User>()` in the example the code is `fn<B>()`

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question, since I've experimented a lot with coding techniques in this area as a platform engineer, so I thought I'd share some suggestions.

I have found that generics on their own do not provide a full solution, or the most readable code. When dealing with API calls it can help to formulate requirements and provide layers with different responsibilities. Here is an example approach that I use in my own apps - expressed via React + Axios.

**REQUIREMENTS**

- React views must get a typesafe experience when dealing with API payloads
- Reliability and retries must be handled by shared classes used in multiple apps, eg to retry API calls, implement circuit breaker or whatever
- Code must be simple and readable

**CODE SNIPPETS**

- [React view model](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/views/companies/companiesContainerViewModel.ts#L34) uses typed API entities without casting and the UI renders this in a type safe manner. All views and view models get this experience.
- [Fetch class](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/api/client/apiFetch.ts) implements low level stuff and could be shared between multiple apps. At one point I used generics here and the code wss much less readable.
- [Service agent class](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/api/client/apiClient.ts). A simple adapter with methods  that serve views in the most natural way. There are casts here but they are only in this layer.
- In other places [limited generics](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample.final/blob/master/spa/src/configuration/configurationLoader.ts) are used, eg to call `axios.get<T>`. However, using generics in many places with separate request and response types quickly gets messy.

**CONCLUSION**

Sometimes layering and separation of concerns provides the cleanest solution, rather than using generics too much. Out of interest the design is portable to any language, and I also use it for mobile apps:

- [Swift API Calls in iOS](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.ios/blob/master/Source/Api/Client/ApiClient.swift)
- [Kotlin API Calls in Android](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.mobilesample.android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/authguidance/basicmobileapp/api/client/ApiClient.kt)

Of course, my code could be improved, eg to validate better before casting - perhaps service agents could manage that. But all developers in a software company would understand my code, which I think is the most important outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Providing this answer but not sure this is what you are expecting as your initial question is missing some info..

```
function foo<T extends (...args: any) => any>(fn: T):()=>ReturnType<typeof fn> {
  return function bar(): ReturnType<typeof fn> 
   {
      return fn({ /*config*/ });
  }
}


  const f1 = () => Promise.resolve(({ value: 'value' } ));
  const x1 = foo(f1)
  const y1 = x1().then(data => data.value); // type of Promise<string> as value is string 

  const f2 = () => Promise.resolve(({ value:1234 } ));
  const x2 = foo(f1)
  const y2 = x2().then(data => data.value); // type of Promise<number> as value is string
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but unfortunately this is not what I'm looking for. Both **f1** and **f2** should be **generic** functions. As a real world example of such functions is `axios.request` which accept response type as a generic type (`axios.request<User>`). So you can look at the example that function `bar` call `axios.request` and pass to it response type. And we call function `bar` by passing some request configuration data. So in this case, function `foo` is a factory which accept `axios.request` and return wrapper around it

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this way is idiomatic for typescript:

```js
function foo<T extends <X>(...args: any) => any>(fn: T) {
  return function bar<B>(): ReturnType<typeof fn> /***/ {
    return fn<B>({ /*config*/ });
  }
}
```

`X` generic parameter is unused. It should be removed.

Consider this example:

```js
const fn = <T,>(): T => [1, 2, 3] as any as T
const result_0 = fn<number[]>() // number[]
const result_1 = fn<number[] & { tag: 42 }>() // number[]
result_1.tag // 42 but undefined in runtime
```

This is very unsafe to use generic type which is not related to any argument. I would even say that it is a bad practice in TypeScript. Also you should never use explicit generic arguments during function call< like here `x1<{ a: 'A' }>()`. Generic `{ a: 'A' }` is not related to any argumenty.

However, there is a amsll expection. You should use explicit generic if you are passing empty array to a function like here:

```js
const array = <T,>(list: T[]) => list
array([]) // never
array<number>([]) // number
```

AFAIK, this is only one case I know where you are forced to provide explicit generic. Maybe there are other exceptions but I don't know about them. If you are interested in function argument inference you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments).

To summarize, this line `x1<{ b: 'B' }>()` is unsafe as well as using `as T` in `<T>() => Promise.resolve(({/*input*/ } as T))`.

ALso, if you want to express type of any function, you should use this annotation `(...args: any[]) => any` instead of this `(...args: any) => any` because `...args` is an array.

Let's go back to the original example. In order to make it safer, I would write it as follow:

```js
type Fn = (...args: any[]) => any

function foo<Callback extends Fn>(fn: Callback) {
  return function bar<Config>(config: Config): ReturnType<typeof fn> /***/ {
    return fn(config);
  }
}
```

We can do even better. Since you want to infer only return type, we can use appropriate generic parameter:

```js
type Fn<Return> = (...args: any[]) => Return

const foo = <Return,>(fn: Fn<Return>) => <Config,>(config: Config) => fn(config);

// data argument should have explicit type annotation
const f1 = (data: { a: 'A' }) => Promise.resolve((data));

const x1 = foo(f1)

x1(42).then(elem => {
  elem.a // "A"
})
```

As you might have noticed, it is possible to reduce function annotation. Also, I have not used explicit `ReturnType<typeof fn>` because typescript is able to infer it.

Comment: Thanks. How would you describe a function like `fetch` or `axios.request` without explicitly passing response data type as generic type? I have simplified the example but in the real case `fn` is a function which make request  and only caller of `fn` know about response data type. I understand your solutions, but they are a variation of the first answer to this question, where `f1` just plain function where we can easily get return type. But in my case I should deal with `fn` like `axios.request` https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/index.d.ts#L192

Comment: What I want is something like `ReturnType<typeof fn<B>>` but this is invalid Type

Comment: @maksimr could you please provide an example with axios ?

Comment: Sure https://codesandbox.io/s/youtrack-typed-api-4jvjb?file=/src/index.ts. You can look at api.ts file. What I want is result of call `api` should have the same type as function which we pass to `createApi`